# High dimensional ball

Tags: geometry, volume, spheres

In high dimension, volume of unit ball goes to 0. It is definitely less than volume of ball in three dimension.

**The question is, then, how the d-dimension ball can contain three dimension ball?**

I thought that 1 volume in three dimension is considered by volume of unit cube.

And 1 volume in d-dimension is considered by volume of unit cube in d-dimension.

So I think that the way to calculate volume in different dimension is different.

Is this right answer? I don't know how to explain this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You _cannot compare_ the 'volume' of the d-dimensional unit ball with the volume of the unit ball in three dimensions; they're in different units (length^d vs. length^3).

Comment: I'm not trying to compare the volume. I just wonder this. x1^2 + … + xn^2 <= 1 contains x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2<=1 if we fix other things 0. In this sense, we can say that high dimensional ball contains lower dimensional ball. But in high dimension, maybe lower dimension ball's volume is considered as 0 just like line or plane in 3-dimension. So I think although high dimension ball contains lower dimension ball, it is considered as 0 volume in high dimension.

Comment: Of course.  The four-dimensional volume of a three-dimensional cube is $0$, just as the three-dimensional volume of a square is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to think about this is in $3$ vs $2$ dimensions because we can visualize what is going on.  The volume of a radius $\frac 12 \ 3-$ball is $\frac 43\pi \frac 18=\frac \pi 6$.  The area of a radius $\frac 12\ 2-$ball (a disk) is $\pi \frac 14=\frac \pi 4$, which is greater than the volume of the sphere that contains it.  The volume of the disk is $0$ because its extent in the third direction is zero.  There is no contradiction because we are talking about different things.